# How to store array on a cookie rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to store an array on rails an getting error on the decoding. 
I use `cookies[:test] = Array.new`
And when I am trying to decode
    @test = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(cookies[:test])
I am getting an error.
Whats the proper way to achieve what I am trying to ?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Use `session`, not `cookies`. You don't have to decode it, rails handles that for you. Create the session the same way you already are:

```
session[:test] = Array.new
```

and when you need it, access it like normal

```
session[:test]
# => []
```

Comment: how can this be the right answer when it doesn't even try to answer the question of storing an array in a cookie?

Comment: @sevenseaca - session does store the array in a cookie

Comment: In a very very limited way (if you use the rails cookie store for sessions), and you cannot set any of the normal cookie options on them.

Comment: Cookies and sessions are different things meant for different (though generally similar) purposes. This answers the wrong question.

Answer (score 6):

The "Rails way" is to use `JSON.generate(array)`, since it's what is used in the second example in the Cookies docs:

```
# Cookie values are String based. Other data types need to be serialized.
cookies[:lat_lon] = JSON.generate([47.68, -122.37])
```

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

When you want to read it back, just use `JSON.parse cookies[:lat_lon]` for example, and it'll provide you an array.

Answer (score 5):

When writing to the cookie I usually convert the array to a string.

```
def save_options(options)
  cookies[:options] = (options.class == Array) ? options.join(',') : ''
end
```

Then I convert back into an array when reading the cookie.

```
def options_array
  cookies[:options] ? cookies[:options].split(",") : []
end
```

I'm not sure if this is "the right way" but it works well for me.

Comment: Obviously be concerned about storing values that contain commas.

Comment: Very true.  In this case I control all of the keys and values since they are application specific settings (like `ShowDetails,TRUE`).  You could, of course, also change the delimiter to something a little more 'safe' if you'd like.